# Firefox UI, Quake glitch, possibly tied to something with QT?

Tags: desktop-environment, qt

First of all I apologize if I'm on the wrong StackExchange entirely, I'm using Linux and this seemed like the best place to find advice because my problem seems to be so niche. I DON'T think it's a problem with firefox or guake on it's own.

None of the top menu buttons in firefox actually do anything. Downloads, bookmarks, settings, nothing actually shows up when I click them.

Guake on the other hand doesn't show the window at all. It seems to be running just fine, and using my shortcut *seems* to deselect whatever window I'm currently on but nothing actually shows up.

The only thing I suspect that might've caused this is I installed qt5-default I presume around the same time. Since then I've tried uninstalling it among other things but nothing has seemed to fix it.

I can't find any errors from Firefox, but Guake returns this when I try to open that window.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/guake_app.py:825: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_window_set_type_hint: assertion '!gtk_widget_get_mapped (GTK_WIDGET (window))' failed self.window.set_type_hint(gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DOCK)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/guake_app.py:826: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_window_set_type_hint: assertion '!gtk_widget_get_mapped (GTK_WIDGET (window))' failed self.window.set_type_hint(gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_NORMAL)
```

EDIT: Bumping my post because I haven't gotten any answers, I don't have any idea what I can do to fix this on my own, and as far as I'm aware this is a "good question" per the recommended guidelines. Once again please correct me if I am mistaken.

EDIT 2: Okay, the problem has been solved. As far as I'm aware I've done absolutely nothing to try and solve this problem, but it's fixed. A quick test reveals that Firefox is working completely as expected now, though it seems Quake is still affected?

EDIT 3:Quake is now working as expected, with literally nothing done on my part (at least not that I'm aware of) to fix the problem. To anyone else who winds up with this issue, I guess just wait until it fixes itself?

Comment: Any recommendations on how I fix this, or any further information you need?

Comment: Gonna try bumping this question by adding a comment, I think that works?

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured, but I wasn't getting any answers to my question, nor was I informed that my question was wrong in anyway